# configure sinatra as a server

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, rackup

I have written an app in ruby using sinatra. the app works fine and I am testing the post/get request using postman.

Right now I start the app using the command `rackup` but it starts the server locally on the port `9292`. using postman, I send the `POST` on `localhost:9292`

I would like to test the app when access from another computer. I expect something using POSTMAN sending a POST on `http://182.12.34.1:9292` but I didn't find how to do this.

config.ru

```
load './app/init.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Any idea, how to switch from local test to a server ?

Thansks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an existing tool like ngrok or localtunnel.

If you have npm installed, then you can do this in a new terminal:

```
sudo npm install -g localtunnel
lt --port 9292
```

It will then give you a URL that you can share. Keep in mind these two things:

1. The URL is only valid as long as the localtunnel process is running
2. You still need to have your server running on localhost:9292 for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps listen to localhost only in the config?

You need to bind the host to `0.0.0.0` otherwise it will only only be available locally...